# Set group_concat_max_len on a PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have the following query:

```
$cases = $conn->prepare("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR '|') as texts, year FROM cases GROUP BY year ORDER BY ano DESC");
$cases->execute();
$cases_result = $cases->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

But some texts are not showing completely

So I have to change the value of group_concat_max_len. I did as follows:

```
mysql_query("SET group_concat_max_len = 2048");
```

But using PDO not know how

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you not use [`$conn->query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)?

```
$conn->query("SET group_concat_max_len = 2048");
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a maximum value?

Comment: yeah, 4,294,967,295 for 32 bit platforms and 18,446,744,073,709,547,520 for 64 bit.